# How to enable recording in Twilio Video conference?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio, twilio-api

I'm having trouble enabling 'RecordParticipantsOnConnect' as stated here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/recordings-resource  in my twilio implementation but i can't seem to get it working, where do i set RecordParticipantsOnConnect to true?

They say you need to pass this option when you're creating a room, but i'm not creating any room, it's done automatically i'm just passing a room name as a string and i get the token:

```
class TwilioServices
  ACCOUNT_SID     = ENV['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
  API_KEY_SID     = ENV['TWILIO_API_KEY_SID']
  API_KEY_SECRET  = ENV['TWILIO_API_KEY_SECRET']

  def self.get_token(type, room)
    # Create an Access Token
    token = Twilio::JWT::AccessToken.new ACCOUNT_SID, API_KEY_SID, API_KEY_SECRET, ttl: 7200, identity: type,

    # Grant access to Video
    grant = Twilio::JWT::AccessToken::VideoGrant.new
    grant.room = room
    token.add_grant grant
    # Serialize the token as a JWT
    token.to_jwt
  end
end
```

How do i solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you are letting the SDK dynamically creating the room when you join it then you won't be able to set the recording flag in your code. Instead, you have two choices:

1. You can [configure your room default settings in the Twilio console](https://www.twilio.com/console/video/configure). Here you can set the rooms to default to group rooms and to turn recording on. (You can't record peer-to-peer rooms because the media does not go through Twilio servers.)
2. You can create your room up front using the [Video Rooms REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/rooms-resource). When creating a room yourself, you can also set the type and whether it is recorded. To do so, you'd update your `get_token` method to something like:

   ```
   class TwilioServices
     ACCOUNT_SID     = ENV['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
     API_KEY_SID     = ENV['TWILIO_API_KEY_SID']
     API_KEY_SECRET  = ENV['TWILIO_API_KEY_SECRET']

     def self.get_token(type, room)
       # Create an Access Token
       token = Twilio::JWT::AccessToken.new ACCOUNT_SID, API_KEY_SID, API_KEY_SECRET, ttl: 7200, identity: type,

       client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(API_KEY_SID, API_KEY_SECRET, ACCOUNT_SID)
       video_room = client.video.rooms.create(
         unique_name: room,
         record_participants_on_connect: true,
         type: 'group'
       )

       # Grant access to Video
       grant = Twilio::JWT::AccessToken::VideoGrant.new
       grant.room = room
       token.add_grant grant
       # Serialize the token as a JWT
       token.to_jwt
     end
   end
   ```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem, although i got confused a bit trying to understand the relatio between video room and token, i mean how the configurations used to create room get passed along with the token, but i believe sharing the same room name "grant.room = room" does the job. Thanks alot

Comment: Yep, the room's identifier is it's name so when you grant access to that room for that token it connects the user to the room you created (as long as they connect within 5 minutes, otherwise the room will be closed).

Comment: One last question @philnash, in my app the room name is always the same everytime a conference is started, it is already statistically defined, but i get an error from Twilio saying that the room already exists, how can i solve this?

Comment: Don't know what you mean by "statistically defined" but if you are running the above code for each person that is trying to join the room then the first person will get in and then the room will be created. You could [use the REST API to try to fetch the room by unique name first](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/rooms-resource#get-instance) and if it exists just create the token, otherwise create the room.

Comment: what i mean is the room unique name isn't unique after all, it's defined like this: room = "GENERAL-ROOM", when i try to reconnect with the same name it says the room is already created.

Comment: In that case you will need some way to make the room name unique. Perhaps a hash of the combination of usernames that are going to enter the room?

Comment: I know, but what i really need is a way to check if the room is already created before triggering the code you suggested, thanks alot for ur help dude.

Comment: So use the REST API to fetch the room by unique name first. See the link above for the details. :)